# Variable may be uninitialized/is used uninitialized

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm writing an English-Metric converter program in C++, and I'm trying to use try, throw, catch to reject negative/non-numeric values in the 'main' function.

My two problems are:

1.)
Whenever I enter, say, 'g' into the console, I get an output: 0 inches is equal to 0 centimeters AND THEN I get the error display that I want to pop up. What i need is only the error display to be output.

2.) When I enter a negative number, like -3, I get the proper conversion as a negative number when I would like it to tell me my input is invalid.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
char menuSelect();
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double inches;
    double centimeters;
    char select;
    try
    {
        do
        {

            if (centimeters < 0.0 || inches < 0.0)
                throw 0;
            if (!cin)
                throw 0;

            select = menuSelect();
            if (select == 'E')
            {
                cout << "Enter the number of inches: ";
                cin >> inches;
                centimeters = inches * 2.54;
                cout << inches << " inches is equal to " << centimeters
                        << " centimeters." << endl;
            }
            else if (select == 'M')
            {
                cout << "Enter the number of centimeters: ";
                cin >> centimeters;
                inches = centimeters / 2.54;
                cout << centimeters << " Centimeters is equal to " << inches
                        << " inches." << endl;
            }

        } while (select != 'Q');

    }
    catch (int errID)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << errID << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a positive number. ";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: "undefined reference to `menuSelect()'" [mcve] please.

Comment: inches and centimeters are both uninitialized where you first use them. If you want to validate your input you'll need to do it where you actually accept it, not in another iteration of the loop.

Comment: Don't test for both  `centimeters < 0.0` and `inches < 0.0`. You might have only set one of them. Worse, if you want `centimeters` checking `inches` is not necessary AND you may error out over an old value negative value in `inches`.

Comment: Please don't use exceptions for flow of control on the main program path. That does not make for good C++.

Comment: You're checking if the input is invalid before you read them and after you outputted the result. Consider going through your program line by line in the order that it gets executed and explain everything to [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like that: (I added a flag `bool bNeg = false`, `if (inches>=0)` and `if (centimeters>=0)` just after the input & if the input is negative for either 'E' or 'M' set `bNeg = true`)

```
    bool bNeg = false;

    if (select == 'E')
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of inches: ";
        cin >> inches;
        if (inches>=0) { // No meaning to negative values
            centimeters = inches * 2.54;
            cout << inches << " inches is equal to " << centimeters
                << " centimeters." << endl;
        }
        else bNeg = true;

    }
    else if (select == 'M')
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of centimeters: ";
        cin >> centimeters;
        if (centimeters>=0) { // No meaning to negative values
            inches = centimeters / 2.54;
            cout << centimeters << " Centimeters is equal to " << inches
                << " inches." << endl;
        }
        else bNeg = true;
    }

    if (bNeg) {
        // tbd: say what you want to say
    }
```

Comment: I recommend marking and explaining what you changed and why you changed it. Answer looks good, but with nothing but code, the asker might learn nothing but an incremental improvement in their cut and pasting skills.